Your default credentials were not found. - Gemini Image
Error
    google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.

Source code
    import vertexai
    from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel, Image
    
    PROJECT_ID = "PROJECT_ID"
    REGION = "us-central1"
    api_key="xxxxx"
    vertexai.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location=REGION,api_key=api_key)
    
    IMAGE_FILE = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\food.jpg"
    image = Image.load_from_file(IMAGE_FILE)
    
    generative_multimodal_model = GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-flash-002")
    response = generative_multimodal_model.generate_content(["What is shown in this image?", image])
    
    print(response)

What is the right way to set the google key from the code?
It uses gemini API key or Google Cloud API Key?
